# How would you say "leather belt with metal buckle"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Are there other option than

> Ledzona zono kun metalbuko

Comment: Why "led*zona* zono" instead of just "leda zono"? That seems unnecessarily redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you should always take translations from Google translate with a large grain of salt, even a blind pig can find an acorn once in a while. That is, there is nothing wrong with the Google translation this time:

- *leda zono kun metala buko*

Comment: Dankon! Mi tro zorgis, hehe. Kiel vi dirus tiun idiomon en Esperanto? "Eĉ blinda porko foje trovas glanon"

Comment: Eĉ blinda kokino povas trovi grajnon (La Proverbaro)